# ¿Cómo envio mensaje whatsapp desde una base de datos con nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, whatsapp

Yo he logrado êxito para envio de mensajes con el metodo POST y http://localhost.
Pero a mi me gustaria hacerlo leyendo un tabla de una base de datos.
¿Que cambios tendria que hacer para la busqueda del numero y el mensaje de la BD?
Este es código para el envio:

```html
    // Send message
app.post(
  "/send-message",
  [body("number").notEmpty(), body("message").notEmpty()],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(({ msg }) => {
      return msg;
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({
        status: false,
        message: errors.mapped(),
      });
    }

    const number = phoneNumberFormatter(req.body.number);
    const message = req.body.message;

    const isRegisteredNumber = await checkRegisteredNumber(number);

    if (!isRegisteredNumber) {
      return res.status(422).json({
        status: false,
        message: "The number is not registered",
      });
    }

    client
      .sendMessage(number, message)
      .then((response) => {
        res.status(200).json({
          status: true,
          response: response,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
          status: false,
          response: err,
        });
      });
  }
);
```

Esto és el result:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! ¿Qué estas usando para hacer el envío de msj a whatsapp? (librería, servicio, etc)

Comment: Estoy usando la librería WhatsApp-web.js. Este es el enlace del video,; https://youtu.be/PF_MWklEQpM

Answer (score 1):

Primero para saber los cambios que deberias hacer tendriamos que saber como te estas conectando a la base de datos, estas usando un ORM? Independiente de lo que uses, podrias llamar desde la ruta a un controlador que se ocupe de llamar a las entidades necesarias para gettear el numero y el mensaje.

Saludos

Comment: Eliás Validez, gracias por contestarme. Yo sé como conectar al BD y añadir las rutas. Pero no lo sé como anãdir el código en este trozo de código que he compartido. Donde está la linea app.post devo añadir los cambios. Por ej.
leer la tabla de datos y traer el numero_whats y el mensaje. Eso es mi duda.

Comment: Saludos @ElíasValdez, es genial que quieras aportar *(aunque obviamente por el momento no tienes los puntos de reputación suficientes para comentar)*, pero reservamos ésta sección para respuestas que resuelvan el problema, te invito a revisar [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así podrás ganar tu primera medalla. ;)